# JMenuBar is not appearing (just showing thin grey line)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenubar

I'm using Eclipse on a Mac running Mavericks, but that shouldn't be the problem. I seem to be doing nothing wrong, I just can't get this `JMenuBar` to show up on my `JFrame` even after trying `repaint()` and `revalidate()`, here's the code and picture of the grey line that is showing up..

create the JFrame.. (this object is created in a Runnable(run()) in the driver)

```
public GUIPhotoAlbum ()
{
    super("PhotoAlbum");
    usersAlbum = new PhotoAlbum();

    setIcon();

    this.setSize(875, 625);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

    initComponents();
    initMenuBar();
    repaint();
    revalidate();

    initTopPanel();
    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    initBottomPanel();
    add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    addListeners();

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

initMenuBar():

```
   private void initMenuBar()
        {
            menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
            editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
            helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");

            openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
            saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
            exitItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
            addItem = new JMenuItem("Add");
            modifyItem = new JMenuItem("Modify");
            deleteItem = new JMenuItem("Delete");
            aboutItem = new JMenuItem("About ...");

            fileMenu.add(openItem);
            fileMenu.add(saveItem);
            fileMenu.add(exitItem);

            editMenu.add(addItem);
            editMenu.add(modifyItem);
            editMenu.add(deleteItem);

            helpMenu.add(aboutItem);

            //sets the menu bar for the JFrame
            this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        }
```

Here's my JFrame window so far:
[image]
..That tiny grey line just below the top bar of frame goes away if you take out `this.setJMenuBar(menuBar)` from code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't add anything to the `JMenuBar`

```
menuBar = new JMenuBar();
fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");

menuBar.add(fileMenu);
menuBar.add(editMenu);
menuBar.add(helpMenu);
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think careffully with [offers anywhere](http://www.releaselyrics.com/57fc/delegation-welcome-to-my-world/)